# 'Vue.js' Errors in communicating between parent and children

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i have application that calls several requests and displays that data. Everything is working, but I getting some errors that I can't figure out where is the problem..

So I have two components:

```
--App :Parent
---Events :Children
```

In App.vue calling children component:

```
<Events :events="gameInfo" :results="results" @startNewGame="startNewGame" />
```

Giving as a props "gameInfo", "results" and listening for "startNewGame" event.

When application loads first time in App.vue i'm calling function:

```
// Get Next Game
    getNextGame() {
      this.gameInfo = [];
      RouletteApi.getNextGame().then(response => {
        this.gameInfo.push({ response });
      });
   }
```

That children component receives and displays data.

In children component:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Events",
  props: ["events", "results"],
  data() {
    return {
      GameStartTime: null,
      GameId: null,
      GameUUID: null
    };
  },
  watch: {
    events: function(newVal, oldVal) {
      this.GameStartTime = newVal[0]["response"].fakeStartDelta--;
      this.GameId = newVal[0]["response"].id;
      this.GameUUID = newVal[0]["response"].uuid;
    }
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (this.GameStartTime > 0) {
        this.GameStartTime = this.events[0]["response"].fakeStartDelta--;
      } else {
        this.$emit("startNewGame", this.GameUUID); -- call to parent function
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
};
</script>
```

I watching, getting the data and setting timer, to execute "startNewGame" function from parent, that will make another api call and give children new data.

After timer expires I'm calling "startNewGame" function from parent:

```
startNewGame(uuid) {
  this.startSpinning();

  RouletteApi.startNewGame(uuid).then(response => {
    if (response.result == null) {

      setTimeout(function() {
        startNewGame(uuid);
      }, 1000);

    } else {
      this.results.push({ response });

      this.gameInfo = []; -- resetting that previous dat 
      this.getNextGame(); -- call to first function in example
    }
  });
```

That checks if response is null then setting timeout and calling that function until response will be not null. If response came not null than I pushing to children result, resetting that gameInfo array and calling again getNextGame() function that will call request and set new value for timer in children component.

RouletteApi.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  getLayout() {
    return axios.get('/configuration')
      .then(response => {
        return response.data
      })
  },

  getStats() {
    return axios.get('/stats?limit=200')
      .then(response => {
        return response.data
      })
  },

  getNextGame() {
    return axios.get('/nextGame')
      .then(response => {
        return response.data
      })
  },

  startNewGame(uuid) {
    return axios.get('/game/' + uuid)
      .then(response => {
        return response.data
      })
  }
}
```

Errors:

```
Error in callback for watcher "events": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined"

TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined
    at VueComponent.events (Events.vue?5cf3:30)

Uncaught ReferenceError: startNewGame is not defined
```

First two errors i'm getting from children component in "watch" part.
Last one when calling function in setInterval in parent component.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53393939/skip-watcher-in-vuejs/53404529#53404529), it seems like the watcher is executed by default the first time the component is loaded and the http call may not be completed before that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the watcher is running before the api call finished. Console log the new value  to see what your get. Try to check if the newVal is not null or an empty array and then set the values.